# Generate KeyPair with RandomSecure

Tags: java, private-key, key-pair, secure-random

Is there anyway I can generate always the same private key? I tired to initialize [KeyPairGenerator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html) with a [RandomSecure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#SecureRandom%28byte[]%29) object which uses the same `seed`:

```
private PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String seed) {
    try {   
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(seed.getBytes());

        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(1024, sr);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        return keyPair.getPrivate();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to generate key pair!");
    }
    return null;
}
```

I invoke the above function and check if the private keys are the same:

```
String seed = "xyzabc123";
PrivateKey key1 = getPrivateKey(seed);
PrivateKey key2 = getPrivateKey(seed);

boolean same = key1.equals(key2); // false
```

They are different, my question is is there a way to generate always the same private key ?

Comment: i think the only way is to create Custom Rsa algotihm

Comment: Do you mean `SecureRandom`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this code will generate same `private-key` at each request. 
Reason behind this is this particular piece of code

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(seed.getBytes());
```

each time you call `getPrivateKey(String)` method. at each time `SecureRandom` Class will generate a new random Number.

```
keyGen.initialize(1024, sr); //each time secure random number will be different.
KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

and `keyGen.initialize()` method initialized with different keys all the time so,each time `keyGen.generateKeyPair();` method will generate a different `private-key`.

If you try to change or pass same `SecureRandom` object in `initialize()` method then only it can be achieved Possibly.

Comment: If you use the same SecureRandom, then it will certainly generate different values on every call.

Answer (score 0):

Java's SecureRandom implementation depends on the available providers, so it can be different on different OS's or for different implementations.

On linux, the default implementation is NativePRNG, which ignores your seed AFAIK.

What you could do is serialize your secure random before you call the generation, and deserialize it to reset it for the next generation.

I've done this in the past, and remember it works for at least some Java implementation.

```
String seed = "xyzabc123";
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(seed.getBytes());
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
out.writeObject(sr);
byte[] superseed = bos.toByteArray();
PrivateKey key1 = getPrivateKey(superseed);
PrivateKey key2 = getPrivateKey(superseed);

private PrivateKey getPrivateKey(byte[] superseed) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(superseed);
    ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    SecureRandom sr = (SecureRandom)in.readObject(); 
...
```